# JTextField permanent Position/Location?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jtextfield, jcreator

So I am a having a problem regarding my JTextField.
What I'm trying to do is to put the JTextField box below the picture(map of a certain town).
Yeah, I used .setBounds and it was already below the image, but what I want to happen is that if I do .pack();, it must be still visible. Unfortunately, it wasn't.

I tried using the .setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5,50,0,50)); and I saw that the box is below the picture but it is no longer available for putting a text.

And to conclude, I want the JTextField below the picture and still must be visible whenever I pack it.

Please Help. Thank you.
I am still on the stage of discovering new things about GUI.
Sorry for the noob question.

```
  import java.awt.BorderLayout;
  import java.awt.Color;
  import java.awt.FlowLayout;
  import java.awt.Font;

  import javax.swing.BorderFactory;
  import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
  import javax.swing.JFrame;
  import javax.swing.JLabel;
  import javax.swing.JPanel;
  import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
  import javax.swing.JTextField;

  class ProgDraftMain {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
        public void run() {
            ProgDraft gui = new ProgDraft();
            gui.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE); 
            gui.setResizable(false);
            gui.pack();
            //gui.setSize(1000 , 1000);
            gui.setVisible(true);           
        }
    });
}
}

class ProgDraft extends JFrame {
private ImageIcon image1;
private JLabel label1;
private JTextField textField1;

ProgDraft() {

    /***Panel**/ 
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setLayout(new FlowLayout(FlowLayout.LEADING));

    /***Title***/
    JLabel title = new JLabel("Perimeter Check", JLabel.CENTER);
    Font font = new Font("Gigi", Font.BOLD, 50);
    title.setFont(font);

    /***Image***/
    ImageIcon pics = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("antipolo.png"));

    JLabel logo = new JLabel(pics);
    logo.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10, 70, 0, 50));
    logo.setToolTipText("Ito raw kunware yung barangay.");
    panel.add(logo);

    /***Info ANtipolo***/
    String text = "Ito kunware ang ANtipolo" + "<br>" +
          "Marami ditong landslide areas" + "<br>" + "<br>" +
          "Take care and stay safe!" + "<br>" +
          "I love my dogs" + "<br>" + "<br>" +"<br>" +
          "Please help!";
    JLabel dog = new JLabel("<html><div style=\"text-align: center;\">" + text + "</html>");
    dog.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5,50,0,50));
    panel.add(dog);

    /***JTextFieldski**/
    JTextField textField = new JTextField(6);
    textField.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(5,50,0,50));
    textField.setBounds(210,470,100,25);
    panel.add(textField);




    getContentPane().setLayout(new BorderLayout());

    getContentPane().add(textField, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    getContentPane().add(dog, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    getContentPane().add(panel, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    getContentPane().add(title, BorderLayout.NORTH);
}
}
```

Comment: you are added `textField` and then `panel` to the `BorderLayout.SOUTH` area, only one (last one) `JComponent` can occupy this area, more info in `Oracle tutorial - How to use Border Layout`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you took my advice yesterday about using `EmptyBorder` a little too far. You are trying to use it for pixel perfect position. That's not what they're meant for. Don't worry about pixel perfect positioning. Like I said yesterday, learn the layout managers and make use of them. Also you can wrap components in panels with different layout managers and nest the panels. You don't have to try and get everything perfect on one panel. Different layout managers have different features and qualities.

For instance What you are trying to do is add two different components to the `BorderLayout.SOUTH`. The thing about `BorderLayout` is each position can only have *one* components. The last one added wins. So what can we do? How about wrapping the two in a panel, then adding *that* panel to the `SOUTH` :-) Easy right?

Also in regards to the EmptyBorders, Make use the the JLabel api. You can `setHorizontalAlignment` to `JLabel.CENTER`. The default is `JLabel.LEADING`, so all the text is to the left. If you set it to the center, then it will be centered.

Also just FYI, setBounds will not work unless you are using null layouts, which I advise against. You don't use it.

Here is the refactor (using NO Empty Borders, letting the layout managers do the job we pay them to do)

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Font;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

class ProgDraftMain {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                ProgDraft gui = new ProgDraft();
                gui.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                gui.setResizable(false);
                gui.pack();
                //gui.setSize(1000 , 1000);
                gui.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}

class ProgDraft extends JFrame {

    private ImageIcon image1;
    private JLabel label1;
    private JTextField textField1;

    ProgDraft() {

        /**
         * Main Panel
         */
        JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        /**
         * *Title**
         */
        JLabel title = new JLabel("Perimeter Check", JLabel.CENTER);
        Font font = new Font("Gigi", Font.BOLD, 50);
        title.setFont(font);
        mainPanel.add(title, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);   // add title to top

        /**
         * *Info ANtipolo**
         */
        String text = "Ito kunware ang ANtipolo" + "<br>"
                + "Marami ditong landslide areas" + "<br>" + "<br>"
                + "Take care and stay safe!" + "<br>"
                + "I love my dogs" + "<br>" + "<br>" + "<br>"
                + "Please help!";
        JLabel dog = new JLabel("<html><div style=\"text-align: center;\">" + text + "</html>");
        dog.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        mainPanel.add(dog);   //   add dog to center

        /**
         * *Image** ==========>>>>>> Make sure to change the image name back.
         */
        ImageIcon pics = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("stackoverflow.png"));

        JLabel logo = new JLabel(pics);
        logo.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        //logo.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(10, 70, 0, 50));
        logo.setToolTipText("Ito raw kunware yung barangay.");

        /**
         *  Wrapper for text field and icon
         */
        JPanel iconFieldPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        JTextField textField = new JTextField(10);    
        iconFieldPanel.add(logo);
        iconFieldPanel.add(textField, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);
        JPanel iconFieldWrapper = new JPanel();
        iconFieldWrapper.add(iconFieldPanel);

        mainPanel.add(iconFieldWrapper, BorderLayout.PAGE_END);  // add icon and field to bottom

        getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
    }
}
```

And pleeease do take some time to go over the link I provided for using layout managers. Study one at a time and get the hang of each. It's an art, so it'll take time, just like anything else.

Comment: Oh yes, you're the one who answered my question yesterday!

Comment: @peeskilet  I am so grateful but I also apologize for not using the proper codes correctly/properly. I am a slow learner and at the same time, I want to see the big picture first before going into the details but I know that's not a reason huhu... I am reading the sites you referred to me, it's just that I'm slow at picking things up. Anyway thank you again! :-) This is a big help.